# Cuando ejecuto el select no aparece el valor correspondiente

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una pagina y al hacer um select en mi base de datos no muestra el valor del campo que coresponde al usuario que esta logueado.

```
session_start();
require 'funcs/conexion.php';

 if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM comissao_usuario  WHERE id='$idUsuario'";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

CODIGO HTML

```
 <div>
    <p>Total Comissões</p>

    <p class="text-blue">R$ <?php echo"". utf8_decode($row['valores'] ) . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);?></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: mostrar el codigo, aun sigo com el problema.

Comment: que viene en idusuario?

Comment: Inicio de SESSION del usuario

Comment: Viene esa cadena? O el id de usuario? Lo chequeaste?

Comment: e añadido lo que faltaba del codigo para tener mas sentido

Answer (score 0):

Tenes un error en la siguiente parte del codigo PHP

> $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
>
> $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

deberia ser:

> $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
>
> $row = **$resultado**->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Hola Feddy gracias por la respuesta, e corregido el error que tenia pero aun asi sigo con el mismo problema, que no aparece nada.